# As a viewer of a YouTube video, can one see whether the video received a copyright claim?

Tags: youtube

I saw a video on YouTube. I am just a viewer: I have not uploaded that video to YouTube. Can I see whether the video received a copyright claim?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes:

- Videos with claims on music may have a "Music" section in the description where the music titles and cover art are listed out.
- Videos using movie clips may have a "buy/rent the full movie" box to the right of the video player.
- Videos with any claim may have a "recommended by <*rights holder*>: <*video title*>" inside the description (before the description even is opened up).
- Videos with any claim may be blocked in your country, with a message stating just that in place of the video player.
- When embedding the video, videos with claims may state that you have to watch on YouTube due to a claim by the right holder. This feature is the only one on this list which also can by applied by the video uploader, in which case it'd say "... disabled by the video owner".

It also is possible that a claim shows none of those options. The presence of one of the above points confirms that a video is claimed by someone, but the absence of it does not confirm the opposite.

Additionally, sufficiently large corporate channels (those with access to Content ID) may claim their own videos to apply any of the above features. So a claim doesn't necessarily mean it's a claim by a third party either.